# Can the Url tag of pom.xml be used in the code

Tags: maven, selenium, automation, pom.xml

pom.xml

https://"baseurl"/

I am writing Automated tests

Instead of mentioning the actual url of my test application, as I have already defined it in pom.xml

Can I in anyway use the Url element in my code

Comment: The question is why do you need the URL in your tests? You can inject the value of the url as a property (see maven-surefire/maven-failsafe plugin)...

Comment: Thx, I wonder whether the URL tag of POM is technically useful in any form !! or is it just like a label sits as a property in Maven

Comment: Usually it will be put into the generated site also ...